# How to open and manipulate Word document/template in Java?

Tags: java, ms-word

I need to open a `.doc/.dot/.docx/.dotx` (I'm not picky, I just want it to work) document, 
parse it for placeholders (or something similar),
put my own data,
and then return generated `.doc/.docx/.dotx/.pdf` document.

And on top of all that, I need the tools to accomplish that to be free.

I've searched around for something that would suit my needs, but I can't find anything.
Tools like Docmosis, Javadocx, Aspose etc. are commercial.
From what I've read, Apache POI is nowhere near successfully implementing this (they currently don't have any official developer working on Word part of framework).

The only thing that looks that could do the trick is OpenOffice UNO API.
But that is a pretty big byte for someone that has never used this API (like me).

So if I am going to jump into this, I need to make sure that I am on the right path.

Can someone give me some advice on this?

Comment: ¿If it's just a matter of replacing some placeholders, why Java?

Comment: Java because this is just a small part of a really big project.
I'll go with docx4j.

Comment: Can you say why commercial out of scope for a big project?  Perhaps JODReports is worth looking at since it is free.

Comment: You mentioned Docmosis - it has a free version too.

Comment: Your solution should be done as an answer. Yes, you can answer your own question here (though of course, it *must be* an answer). Then you can mark it as the correct answer; you won't get any reputation from that (but will if others vote it up) but it can still help other people in the same situation.

Comment: Done!
Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I know it's been a long time since I've posted this question, and I said that I would post my solution when I'm finished.
So here it is.

I hope that it will help someone someday.
This is a full working class, and all you have to do is put it in your application, and place TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY_ROOT directory with .docx templates in your root directory.

Usage is very simple.
You put placeholders (key) in your .docx file, and then pass file name and Map containing corresponding key-value pairs for that file.

Enjoy!

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class DocxManipulator {

    private static final String MAIN_DOCUMENT_PATH = "word/document.xml";
    private static final String TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY_ROOT = "TEMPLATES_DIRECTORY/";


    /*    PUBLIC METHODS    */

    /**
     * Generates .docx document from given template and the substitution data
     * 
     * @param templateName
     *            Template data
     * @param substitutionData
     *            Hash map with the set of key-value pairs that represent
     *            substitution data
     * @return
     */
    public static Boolean generateAndSendDocx(String templateName, Map<String,String> substitutionData) {

        String templateLocation = TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY_ROOT + templateName;

        String userTempDir = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        userTempDir = TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY_ROOT + userTempDir + "/";

        try {

            // Unzip .docx file
            unzip(new File(templateLocation), new File(userTempDir));       

            // Change data
            changeData(new File(userTempDir + MAIN_DOCUMENT_PATH), substitutionData);

            // Rezip .docx file
            zip(new File(userTempDir), new File(userTempDir + templateName));

            // Send HTTP response
            sendDOCXResponse(new File(userTempDir + templateName), templateName);

            // Clean temp data
            deleteTempData(new File(userTempDir));
        } 
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    /*    PRIVATE METHODS    */

    /**
     * Unzipps specified ZIP file to specified directory
     * 
     * @param zipfile
     *            Source ZIP file
     * @param directory
     *            Destination directory
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static void unzip(File zipfile, File directory) throws IOException {

        ZipFile zfile = new ZipFile(zipfile);
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zfile.entries();

        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
          ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
          File file = new File(directory, entry.getName());
          if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            file.mkdirs();
          } 
          else {
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            InputStream in = zfile.getInputStream(entry);
            try {
              copy(in, file);
            } 
            finally {
              in.close();
            }
          }
        }
      }


    /**
     * Substitutes keys found in target file with corresponding data
     * 
     * @param targetFile
     *            Target file
     * @param substitutionData
     *            Map of key-value pairs of data
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    private static void changeData(File targetFile, Map<String,String> substitutionData) throws IOException{

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String docxTemplate = "";
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(targetFile), "UTF-8"));
            String temp;
            while( (temp = br.readLine()) != null)
                docxTemplate = docxTemplate + temp; 
            br.close();
            targetFile.delete();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            br.close();
            throw e;
        }

        Iterator substitutionDataIterator = substitutionData.entrySet().iterator();
        while(substitutionDataIterator.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry<String,String> pair = (Map.Entry<String,String>)substitutionDataIterator.next();
            if(docxTemplate.contains(pair.getKey())){
                if(pair.getValue() != null)
                    docxTemplate = docxTemplate.replace(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue());
                else
                    docxTemplate = docxTemplate.replace(pair.getKey(), "NEDOSTAJE");
            }
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try{
            fos = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
            fos.write(docxTemplate.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            fos.close();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Zipps specified directory and all its subdirectories
     * 
     * @param directory
     *            Specified directory
     * @param zipfile
     *            Output ZIP file name
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static void zip(File directory, File zipfile) throws IOException {

        URI base = directory.toURI();
        Deque<File> queue = new LinkedList<File>();
        queue.push(directory);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(zipfile);
        Closeable res = out;

        try {
          ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(out);
          res = zout;
          while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            directory = queue.pop();
            for (File kid : directory.listFiles()) {
              String name = base.relativize(kid.toURI()).getPath();
              if (kid.isDirectory()) {
                queue.push(kid);
                name = name.endsWith("/") ? name : name + "/";
                zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));
              } 
              else {
                if(kid.getName().contains(".docx"))
                    continue;  
                zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));
                copy(kid, zout);
                zout.closeEntry();
              }
            }
          }
        } 
        finally {
          res.close();
        }
      }

    /**
     * Sends HTTP Response containing .docx file to Client
     * 
     * @param generatedFile
     *            Path to generated .docx file
     * @param fileName
     *            File name of generated file that is being presented to user
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static void sendDOCXResponse(File generatedFile, String fileName) throws IOException {

        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext
                .getResponse();

        BufferedInputStream input = null;
        BufferedOutputStream output = null;

        response.reset();
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
        response.setHeader("Content-Length",String.valueOf(generatedFile.length()));

        input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(generatedFile), 10240);
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), 10240);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
        for (int length; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        output.flush();
        input.close();
        output.close();

        // Inform JSF not to proceed with rest of life cycle
        facesContext.responseComplete();
    }


    /**
     * Deletes directory and all its subdirectories
     * 
     * @param file
     *            Specified directory
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void deleteTempData(File file) throws IOException {

        if (file.isDirectory()) {

            // directory is empty, then delete it
            if (file.list().length == 0)
                file.delete();
            else {
                // list all the directory contents
                String files[] = file.list();

                for (String temp : files) {
                    // construct the file structure
                    File fileDelete = new File(file, temp);
                    // recursive delete
                    deleteTempData(fileDelete);
                }

                // check the directory again, if empty then delete it
                if (file.list().length == 0)
                    file.delete();
            }
        } else {
            // if file, then delete it
            file.delete();
        }
    }

    private static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
          int readCount = in.read(buffer);
          if (readCount < 0) {
            break;
          }
          out.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
        }
      }

      private static void copy(File file, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
          copy(in, out);
        } finally {
          in.close();
        }
      }

      private static void copy(InputStream in, File file) throws IOException {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        try {
          copy(in, out);
        } finally {
          out.close();
        }
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, @kensvebary. Sadly, this approach will not work reliably. Word injects all sorts of addition tags in the middle of words, making it difficult to find the placeholders. Let's say you have a placeholder named %%employeeId%%. Word may (or may not) render it as such:

`<w:sz w:val="20"/><w:szCs w:val="20"/></w:rPr><w:t>%</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="001768BD"><w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:sz w:val="20"/><w:szCs w:val="20"/></w:rPr><w:t>%</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="007B7AEE"><w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:sz w:val="20"/><w:szCs w:val="20"/></w:rPr><w:t>employeeId%</w:t></w:r>`

The same would happen with RTF.

Comment: I tried it and it works great. To pass replace the content one may use [[ReplaceContent]]. This works fine

Comment: It's a good start, even though it may not be very robust. Even when you use simple placeholders, I wonder what happens at end-of-lines: I guess Word is coding carriage returns, hyphens... with xml tags that may break the replacement string ?

Answer (score 5):

Since a docx file is merely a zip-archive of xml files (plus any binary files for embedded objects such as images), we met that requirement by unpacking the zip file, feeding the document.xml to a template engine (we used [freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/)) that does the merging for us, and then zipping the output document to get the new docx file.

The template document then is simply an ordinary docx with embedded freemarker expressions / directives, and can be edited in Word.

Since (un)zipping can be done with the JDK, and Freemarker is open source, you don't incur any licence fees, not even for word itself.

The limitation is that this approach can only emit docx or rtf files, and the output document will have the same filetype as the template. If you need to convert the document to another format (such as pdf) you'll have to solve that problem separately.

Comment: Another limitation is that you can't readily do anything which creates part relationships (eg images, hyperlinks)

Comment: Yes, if you need to insert dynamic images you'll have to develop a freemarker tag to insert the image reference and include the image data in the zip. Off-hand, I don't see the problem with hyperlinks.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up relying on Apache Poi 3.12 and processing paragraphs (separately extracting paragraphs also from tables, headers/footers, and footnotes, as such paragraphs aren't returned by [XWPFDocument.getParagraphs()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#getParagraphs()) ).

The processing code ([~100 lines](https://github.com/bfab/docx-template-expander/blob/master/src/main/java/docxtemplateexpander/DocxProcessor.java)) and unit tests are [here on github](https://github.com/bfab/docx-template-expander/).

Answer (score 0):

I've been in more or less the same situation as you, I had to modify a whole bunch of MS Word merge templates at once.  After having googled a lot to try to find a Java solution I finally installed Visual Studio 2010 Express which is free and did the job in C#.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!
You gave me some guidlines.

I think I'll start with docx4j library.
And add some custom code where needed.

I'll post the solution when I finish.

Comment: @kensvebary how are your solution at the end? I need the same solution as yours, please give me a feedback as you see. Thanks advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have recently dealt with similar problem:
"A tool which accepts a template '.docx' file, processes the file by evaluation of passed parameter context and outputs a '.docx' file as the result of the process."

finally god brought us [scriptlet4dox](https://github.com/snowindy/scriptlet4docx) :).
the key features for this product is:
1. groovy code injection as scripts in template file (parameter injection, etc.)
2. loop over collection items in table

and so many other features.
but as I checked the last commit on the project is performed about a year ago, so there is a probability that the project is not supported for new features and new bug-fixes. this is your choice to use it or not.