# How to read specially word Word document/template in java

Tags: java

I need read special word from docx and replace it in java.

I found this post [How to open and manipulate Word document/template in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379580/how-to-open-and-manipulate-word-document-template-in-java) works fine but one problem the speciall word may separated in `document.xml` file, and my replace do not works.

How can I read from `document.xml` just my keyword for replace?

Comment: for example $name$ this word in document.xml may (or may not) render it as such: <w:sz w:val="20"/><w:szCs w:val="20"/></w:rPr><w:t>$</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="001768BD"><w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:sz w:val="20"/><w:szCs w:val="20"/></w:rPr><w:t>name</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="007B7AEE"><w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:sz w:val="20"/><w:szCs w:val="20"/></w:rPr><w:t>$</w:t></w:r> and my replace does't works